# Google Sheets - create range (rows) with script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

absolutely no experience with JS but some with C, Excel VB and PHP. I have Google Sheets situation as follows:

- one document, 20 sheets
- need to insert range/rows into one Sheet (17th) and want the same action in all of the other sheets or every other sheet

The way I see it:

1. manually load document
2. activate needed sheet (say #17)
3. start script from the menu

   Pseudo code

   ```
   // read user input, where to insert and how many rows

   var startPosition = prompt ("Where do you wish to insert range/rows?");
   var numRows = prompt ("How many rows do you wish to insert?");

   parse both inputs with some method (?);
   convert first to cell name (e.g. A15);
   convert the second to int;

   // loop through all (or some) sheets

   for (test condition, increment) {

   activate other sheet(s);
   insert row(s);
   loop again;

   }
   ```

ANY help greatly appreciated. I need to finish an assignment and don't have time to learn JavaScript properly

Answer (score 0):

In the TOOLS menu, choose Script Editor.  Then enter this code:

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Display User Dialog', 'displayUserDialog')
      .addToUi();
};
```

Refresh the browser tab, and see if a new custom menu shows up in the menu bar.

Add code for a Dialog Box to prompt the user:

```
function displayUserDialog() {

  Logger.log('displayUserDialog ran: ');

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Dialog Choices')
    .evaluate()
    .setWidth(500)
    .setHeight(450)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog Title');
};
```

Create an HTML file named Dialog Choices:

```
<div>
  <input id="idToCol" type='text' placeholder='input something:'>
  <br>
  <input id="idToRow" type='text' placeholder='Row to Get:'>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Do Stuff" id="idCopyBtn" onclick="fncFunctionName()">


</div>

<script>

function fncFunctionName(){
  console.log('func ran');
}

</script>
```